# How to get acceleration in android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

think the result would be in M/S and this must be a float type

```
float aceleration=??
```

I have read a little about sensor in android but it return 3 values X,Y and Z
now what is the next? or what value is the aceleration?

```
aceleration=?;// (Do I need some mathematical formula??) which one?

mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

think you are in a car and this start to move then there is an acceleration
think now you stop then there is an desacceleration
then acceleration=???

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

float aceleration=??? //how can i get the acceleration here?
```

}

Comment: think you are in a car and this start to move then there is an acceleration think now you stop then there is an desacceleration then acceleration=??? When the cars stop there is a negative acceleration. Acceleration can be positive or negative. Negative acceleration is a more technical word then deceleration.